# Application loader hangs on extracting archive

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am trying to upload application to app store using application loader (version 3.2).

After sign in when i select ipa, application loader hangs on Extracting archive.

Any one face this problem? how to solve it?

Comment: the "Application Loader" becomes unresponsive ? Maybe you must wait a little more time until it finishes extracting.

Comment: Yes Application Loader become unresponsive. but its more than 30 minutes....still its extracting...if i right click on application loader icon on dock, it shows application not responding

Comment: Try to restart app, (maybe OS X too) or you can try to upload application from the Xcode.

Comment: I tried force close application loader and upload again but same problem.

Comment: I create new build and this works fine. and upload quickly...

Comment: have you cleaned project or removed derived data before making new build ?

Comment: No...i just create new build without doing anything...and new build works fine..don't know whats wrong with old one